# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as' , whats wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *,
          isnull(
                   (SELECT sum(amount)
                    FROM v_open_incoming_ar_detail
                    WHERE inc_ar_id <> 4817
                      AND ar_invoice_no = v_payment.[Invoice No.]),0) AS [Have Paid]
   FROM
     (SELECT ID,
             ar_invoice_no AS [Invoice No.],
             ar_invoice_date AS [Invoice Date],
             due_date AS [Due Date],
             po_no AS [Po No.],
             po_date AS [PO Date],
             grand_total AS [Amount],
             tax_pph AS [Tax PPh],
             amount AS [Current Paid]
      FROM v_open_incoming_ar_detail
      WHERE inc_ar_id = 4817 ) v_payment
   GROUP BY ID,
            [Invoice No.],
            ar_invoice_date AS [Invoice Date],
            [Due Date],
            [PO No.],
            [PO Date],)
```

Comment: Can you please format your query ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Isn't there an `as` in the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: This is why whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation, instead of all left aligned text, and line breaks, really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: If you actually used line breaks, you'd have got the error was on line 23 (or similar), not line 1, and spotted it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't alias in a group by , you have a dangling comma after ,[PO Date]  in the group by and you didn't alias the subquery.

```
select * 
from 
(select *,
 isnull(
 (select sum(amount) from v_open_incoming_ar_detail 
 where inc_ar_id <> 4817 
 and ar_invoice_no = v_payment.[Invoice No.]),0) as [Have Paid] 
 from 
 (select ID,ar_invoice_no as [Invoice No.],
  ar_invoice_date as [Invoice Date], due_date as [Due Date],
  po_no as [Po No.],po_date as [PO Date],
  grand_total as [Amount], 
  tax_pph as [Tax PPh], 
  amount as [Current Paid] 
  from v_open_incoming_ar_detail 
  where inc_ar_id = 4817 ) v_payment 
  
  group by ID,[Invoice No.],ar_invoice_date, --as [Invoice Date],
  [Due Date] ,[PO No.] ,[PO Date]            --, 
  ) as aliasname
```